# How do I make OpenOffice open all Microsoft Office files?

Tags: openoffice, file-association

I installed Microsoft Word viewer and then some compatibility update. It re-assigned MS Office files not to open by OpenOffice.

Is there a way I can make OpenOffice to open all MS Office files if I double click MS Office files?

I have already OpenOffice installed.

Comment: FYI, as of now, the OOoAssociation Utility that I just downloaded and installed on my Windows 7 machine does not work. It runs and says that is set the associations. But the associations are not there in fact, and the XLS and XLSX files, for example, are still orphaned with no association. Maybe that utility is out-of-date. Just thought I would share my own experience. Your experience may vary (of course).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OpenOffice forums provide a [nice tutorial](http://user.services.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=12918).  The simplest method is probably to just download and install the [OOoAssociation Utility](http://www.westmesatech.com/files/OOoAssoc.msi) which will set everything up for you automatically.

The OO installer will also give you the option to make these associations automatically.  If you have already installed OO, just go to the Add/Remove Programs dialog in windows and select "Uninstall" on the OpenOffice entry.  This will bring up a window which will allow you to "Repair or Modify" your installation.  Go through the installer and select the option to associate OpenOffice with the document formats.

Comment: The association utility works like a charm. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

**Windows XP**

> **1)** The easiest method is to simply
> right click on a file that you want to
> open. Select 'Open With...', then
> 'Choose Program...'.
>
> From the dialog box that pops up
> select the program you want to make
> the default application (if it was a
> doc file then select swriter if you
> want Open Office to handle these files
> or Microsoft Word if you prefer that).
> You should be able to find it, but if
> you can't you can press 'Browse' and
> search for the program's main
> executable file.
>
> Select "Always use the selected
> program to open this kind of file",
> and press OK. Now this program is the
> default. You can repeat this process
> for various file types (e.g. doc, xls
> etc.).
>
> **2)** Or tell Windows what program to use
> to open what type of files:
>
> This application has been reported to
> be successful in this forum. Running
> this utility should set the
> associations correctly: OOoAssociation
> Utility.
>
> **3)** The other option is to open Windows
> Explorer and then select:
> Tools->Folder Options...->File Types
>
> From here you can find a particular
> file type such as 'doc', and press
> 'Change' and you will be presented
> with the same dialog as in step 1. You
> can use this list to quickly set the
> default application for all the
> relevant file types.

**Windows Vista**

> Methods 1 and 2 for Windows XP will work for Vista too, but there is also another option. It's not often I have good things to say about Vista, but I am pleased to announce that this is definitely one occasion where it can make life easier.
>
> **4)** Start button->Control Panel->Programs->Default Programs->Set your default programs
> . Now find OpenOffice.org or Microsoft Office in the list and after selecting the appropriate one you can either choose 'Set this program as default' to make it the default application for all file types it can handle in one fell swoop, or 'Choose defaults for this program' to quickly pick the file types you would like this program to handle.

Resource from this  [thread](http://user.services.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=12918)

Comment: sad looks like I was late to answer this first :P

Comment: better second than no answer. People can learn from your answer too. Thank you for the effort!

Answer (score 0):

I am using Windows 10 Pro. I am hoping this also works on the Windows 10 Home edition.

To get Microsoft Office documents to open in OpenOffice go to:

**Start> Setting> Apps> Default apps> Set default by app> OpenOffice 4.1.7> Manage**

Select the Microsoft Office document type and change it to OpenOffice.